Opciones de spinner no se ven
Estoy utilizando la plantilla de android studio, el que tiene un menu lateral, puse un spinner
 <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/sp1"
        android:layout_width="378dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="312dp"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_input"
        android:popupBackground="@color/white"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.303"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView16"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"
        android:textColor="@color/black" />

ya cargue las opciones, no tengo problema con eso, mi problema es que el popupBackground del spinner, quisiera que fuera blanco, y al ejecutar la app en mi cel, el spinner si abre, pero el texto no esta en negro, a pesar de que lo puse, y las opciones no se miran
como se que se no muestran???
porque al quitar el popupBackground, parece que por default es negro, y las opciones(letras) estan en blanco y si se miran, pero al seleccionar alguna, no se ve en el input,aunque seguramente si cambio el valor, pero no puedo verlo, como puedo resolver eso??

En este caso debes crear un layout específico para cada elemento y aquí definirías el color del texto, con esto asegurarías se muestre sin problema.
Crea el archivo spinner_list_item.xml dentro de res/layout:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:padding="4dp"
    android:textSize="14sp"/>

Ahora este layout relacionalo a tu Adapter, donde listadoDatos contiene la información para llenar el Spinner:
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.spinner_list_item, listadoDatos);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_list_item);

